# How to save time from a stopwatch and display that time in another html page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```html
function runTimer() {
    currentTime = leadingZero(timer[0]) + ":" + leadingZero(timer[1]) + ":" + leadingZero(timer[2]);

    theTimer.innerHTML = currentTime;
    timer[3]++;

    timer[0] = Math.floor((timer[3]/100)/60);
    timer[1] = Math.floor((timer[3]/100) - (timer[0] * 60));
    timer[2] = Math.floor(timer[3] - (timer[1] * 100) - (timer[0] * 6000));
}
```

So I am currently working on a Typing Test project in javascript and how my program currently works is that when the user first starts typing up the prompt, the stopwatch timer will start timing the user. Once the user finishes typing the prompt, the stopwatch will stop timing and then the user will be taken to an end page which should display the user's time. However I am having issues with trying to save the user's time. For example if User A finishes the test in 15 secs, the program should save the user's time and then display it in the next page which I will take them to.

I have tried using the localStorage.setItem function but just end up getting [object HTML Element] on my page instead of the score. Below I attached my code related to the timer function of my program. I basically want to save the time of it by using local storage but it won't work.

Comment: where is your code which shows how you are attempting to write to localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I have come up with is to send the user's time in the new URL as a parameter. When your timing stops, add this line:

```
window.location = 'your/new/page/location.html?time=' + time;
```

time - is the user's time. As you see, the parameter goes after '?' sign. So, on the new page you will be able to get this parameter with this line:

```
var usersTime = window.location.search.split('=')[1];
```

Here "search" method takes the part of the URL after '?' sign (including it) - it is going to be "?time=15". And then you split this line with '=' sing as a separator and take the second part, which is the number 15.

Answer (score 0):

The local storage stores items as strings.
Therefor the easiest way would be to store the start time and the end time.

So, when the user starts, call:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("starttime", Date.now());
```

and when the user finishes, call:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("endtime", Date.now());
```

This will give you 2 timestamps, which you can then use to format your display.

Get the timestamps in your next page with:

```
starttime = window.localStorage.getItem("starttime");
endtime = window.localStorage.getItem("endtime");

totalseconds = (endtime - starttime) / 1000;
```

then use totalseconds to work out hours/minutes/seconds etc

If you need to display the timer on the screen as the user is typing, you can just use

```
totalseconds = (Date.now() - window.localStorage.getItem("starttime")) / 1000;
```

I've tested this in Chrome and it works fine.